# Warning in converting YUV color format to RGB in FFmpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I have YUV420P to RGB format conversion algorithm (given below), but this is giving
following warning while compiling.. Also showing memory leaks in valgrind..

warning: ‘SwsContext* sws_getContext(int, int, PixelFormat, int, int, PixelFormat, int, SwsFilter*, SwsFilter*, const double*)’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/ffmpeg.h264/include/libswscale/swscale.h:191)

```
void YUV2RGB(const IplImage *yuvImg, IplImage *rgbImg) const
{
  //code
  struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(w, h, PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                                       w, h, PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                                       SWS_BICUBIC,NULL, NULL, NULL);
  //code


}
```

Can anybody tell how to correct the memory leak and remove the warning

Comment: Use sws_getContextCached or similar named instead to remove the warning (see doc)

Comment: should I replace sws_getContext by sws_getContextCached ??

Comment: Just have a look at the doc: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/group__lsws.html#gaf360d1a9e0e60f906f74d7d44f9abfdd Note
this function is to be removed after a saner alternative is written
Deprecated:
Use sws_getCachedContext() instead.

Comment: Memory leak: do you release the IplImages that you create with 'cvCreateImage' later?

Comment: In foo() I am releasing allocated image after YUV2RGB(), not given that part in above code

Comment: I have used sws_getCachedContext() instead of sws_getContext(). Now I am not getting any warning......

Comment: can you post your new warning(s)?

Comment: Now I am NOT getting any warning !

Comment: ah ok, but your memory leak is still present?

Comment: after using sws_getCachedContext(), I didn't verify memory leak using valgrind

Comment: My program is crashing..

Comment: struct SwsContext * img_convert_ctx = NULL;

    sws_getCachedContext(img_convert_ctx,
                         w, h, (::PixelFormat) PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 
                         w, h, (::PixelFormat) PIX_FMT_BGR24,   
                         SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

Comment: I have replaced sws_getCachedContext() by above code, while running my program its crashing inside YUV2RGB() function

Comment: did your code work with `sws_getContext`?

Comment: Yes it was working perfectly, but it was giving some compile time warning,  when I am using sws_getCachedContext() I am not getting any compile time warning but it is crashing..

Comment: When I put some cout statements in the above code, it was executing cout statement after sws_getCachedContext(), but it was not executing cout statement that I have put after sws_scale()

Comment: in fact, according to doc, `sws_getCachedContext` internally calls `sws_getContext` if the context is `NULL`, so there should be no change to your pervious code at all. Did you change anything else?

Comment: can you add a `if(img_convert_ctx == 0) std::cout << "ERROR: got no context" << std::endl; ` before the call of `sws_scale` ?

Comment: Its printing ERROR: got no context

Comment: probably you have to use the return value: `struct SwsContext * img_convert_ctx = NULL; img_convert_ctx = sws_getCachedContext(img_convert_ctx, w, h, (::PixelFormat) PIX_FMT_YUV420P, w, h, (::PixelFormat) PIX_FMT_BGR24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: Yes that is correct :-)  Now I am getting RGB images..

Comment: In the documentation it is written that - "Checks if context can be reused, otherwise reallocates a new one" : but in my function each time I am creating new SwsContext and deleting at the end of the function. If I am making img_convert_ctx (SwsContext) as a member variable of the class in which I have defined YUV2RGB(). So I will be using same `img_convert_ctx` for every function call, will the execution be fast by re-using img_convert_ctx ?

Comment: yes, that's what the cached context call is made for. Just be sure that you dont use `sws_freeContext` too early and dont forget to initialize the member variable with NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67149/discussion-between-deepak-and-micka).