# How to optimize YUV to RGB color conversion code

Tags: c++, opencv, optimization, ffmpeg

I have written a function to convert an image in YUV420P to RGB but it is taking 30 millisecond to convert an image (size: 1280 x 720) into RGB, but when I am using ffmpeg function ( [as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519056/warning-in-converting-yuv-color-format-to-rgb-in-ffmpeg)) to convert YUV image into RGB its taking only 2 millisecond for the same image. What is the problem with my code ? How can I optimize the code that I have written ??
My code is given below

```
 int step = origImage->widthStep;
 uchar *data = (uchar *)origImage->imageData; 
 int size = origImage->width * origImage->height;
 IplImage* img1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(origImage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i<origImage->height; i++)
    {
      for (int j=0; j<origImage->width; j++)
      {
        float Y = data[i*step + j];
        float U = data[ (int)(size + (i/2)*(step/2)  + j/2) ];
        float V = data[ (int)(size*1.25 + (i/2)*(step/2) + j/2)];

        float R = Y + 1.402 * (V - 128);
        float G = Y - 0.344 * (U - 128) - 0.714 * (V - 128);
        float B = Y + 1.772 * (U - 128);


        if (R < 0){ R = 0; } if (G < 0){ G = 0; } if (B < 0){ B = 0; }
        if (R > 255 ){ R = 255; } if (G > 255) { G = 255; } if (B > 255) { B = 255; }

        cvSet2D(img1, i, j,cvScalar(B,G,R));
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'd start by using integer math instead of floating point. Then see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fastest-way-to-clamp-an-integer-to-the-range-0-255

Comment: Should be moved to code review.

Comment: find a way to remove the 6 if statements, make sure that the arithmetic produces values in the correct range and as Mark Ransom said, use integer math

Comment: @ Park Young-Bae : it was by mistake..

Comment: [The ffmpeg code is hand-optimized assembly that uses SIMD instructions](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libswscale/x86/yuv2rgb_template.c;h=acb78f520e48a56b3878eeb2eb72082a39643015;hb=HEAD). You can improve your code (by doing fewer float/double/int/char conversions, for example), but to be honest you won't be as fast as ffmpeg unless you do fancy assembly/MMX tricks like they do. But perhaps you could use OpenCV's `cvtColor` function, which ought to be fairly optimized.

Comment: is it not possible to use some pre-calced table for the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this(should reduce to 25 milliseconds):

```
 int step = origImage->widthStep;
 uchar *data = (uchar *)origImage->imageData; 
 int size = origImage->width * origImage->height;
 IplImage* img1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(origImage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

    int stepDb2=step /2;
    float sizeMb1d25=size*1.25 ;
    int origImagePTheight=origImage->height;
    int origImagePTwidth=origImage->width;
    for (int i = 0; i<origImagePTheight; i++)
    {
      float idb2=i/2;
      int iStep=i*step;
      for (int j=0; j<origImagePTwidth; j++)
      {
        float variable=idb2*stepDb2  + j/2;
        float Y = data[iStep + j];
        float U = -128 + data[ (int)(size + variable) ];
        float V = -128 + data[ (int)(sizeMb1d25 + variable)];

        float R = Y + 1.402 * V ;
        float G = Y - 0.344 * U - 0.714 * V;
        float B = Y + 1.772 * U;

        R= R * !(R<0);
        G= G * !(G<0);
        B= B * !(B<0);

        R=R*(!(R>255)) + 255 * (R>255);
        G=G*(!(G>255)) + 255 * (G>255);
        B=B*(!(B>255)) + 255 * (B>255);

        cvSet2D(img1, i, j,cvScalar(B,G,R));
      }
    }
```

Comment: time reduced by 2-3 millisecond

Comment: what happens when you comment cvSet2D(img1, i, j,cvScalar(B,G,R)); out?

Comment: there is 1 millisecond reduction

Comment: If I comment float R = Y + 1.402 * V ;
        float G = Y - 0.344 * U - 0.714 * V;
        float B = Y + 1.772 * U;  and cvSet2D()  the processing time is less than 1 millisecond

Comment: If I comment only the lines which calculates R, G, B then processing time becomes 18 millisecond ((
        float R = Y + 1.402 * V ;
        float G = Y - 0.344 * U - 0.714 * V;
        float B = Y + 1.772 * U;))

Comment: I think the code you provided to limit range between 0 and 255 is not efficient compared to `if` checking that I have used ! ...